# Minimum no of swaps to be done in an array such that, no two adjacent elements are same

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, arrays, backtracking, c++

Given an array of size n, find minimum number of swaps required, so that no two adjacent elements are equal. For ex-

> n = 6, a[] = {1, 1, 5, 2, 5, 5}, answer = 1, ( swap a[0] with a[4] or
> a[5] )
>
> n = 8, a[] = {1, 5, 5, 1, 4, 6, 1, 1}, answer = 2, (swap (a[0] with
> a[1]) and (a[5] with a[6]) )
>
> n = 8, a[] = {3, 1, 1, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5}, answer = 2, (swap (a[0] with
> a[1]) and (a[5] with a[6]) )

(0-based indexing used in above examples.)

I came up with a recursive/backtracking solution for it.

```
int finalans=INT_MAX;
bool check(vector<int> a)
{
    for(int i=1;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        if(a[i-1]==a[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
void minimumSwaps(vector<int> &a, int swaps=0,int idx)
{
    if(check(a))
    {
        finalans=min(finalans,swaps);
    }
    for(int i=idx;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<a.size();j++)
        {
            swap(a[i],a[j]);
            minimumSwaps(a,swaps+1,i+1);
            swap(a[i],a[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
int n;cin>>n;
vector<int> a(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>a[i];

minimumSwaps(a,0,0);

cout<<finalans<<endl;
}
```

However if the length of array is of order 10^5, Time complexity will become very large. Is there any way to do it in polynomial time complexity?

**Update:** I found this question on the discussion forum of codeforces ([link](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/53781)) and similar question using strings on leetcode ([link](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/1304006/Google-or-Onsite-Interview-or-Form-the-sequence-of-team-members)) as well.